# modifying a number list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of numbers, containing integers of 4 characters in length

I've tried working with filenames and appending the list to the filename as text

```
filename4 = 'password4.txt'
with open("password4.text", "a+") as f:
        for n in range(9999):
            f.write("%d\r" % (n+1))
        f.close()
```

I expected to get the result from 999 to 9999, however my result is 1 to 9999.
Is there a way I can strip the first set of numbers from 1 to 999 from the list, Thanks in advance

Comment: Try googling "python range" and reading the description.

Comment: You want `for n in range(999, 10000)` without the `n + 1`.

Comment: You just need to correct your range parameters! Check my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Study about range function

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

although youu said you want no. with four characters then function will be from **`range(1000,10000)`** as in second parameter the result will be from 1000 to 9999

```
filename4 = 'password4.txt'
with open("password4.text", "a+") as f:
    for n in range(999,9999):# start loop from 999 and end at 9999
        f.write("%d\r" % (n+1))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your range conditions are wrong, you want to use `range(1000,10000)`, which gives you numbers from `1000 to 9999`.

The range function docs say: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

> start:The value of the start parameter (or 0 if the parameter was not supplied)
>   stop:The value of the stop parameter.
>   step:The value of the step parameter (or 1 if the parameter was not supplied)

So your start=1000 and stop=10000

```
filename4 = 'password4.txt'
with open("password4.text", "a+") as f:
    for n in range(1000,10000):
        f.write("%d\r" % (n+1))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

just use range(999,9999) instead of range(9999)

Comment: That's not right. Without modifying anything else, you would need `range(998, 9999)`.

Comment: he asked to strip 1-999, for that range(1000,9999).

Comment: even if he wants to include 999, parameters of range function will be 999,9999

Comment: OP says "from 999 to 9999", and in the `print` statement itself there's `n+1`.